# Making SpriteNode position on path relative to yPos of other SKSpriteNode

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a SpriteKit game using Swift and Xcode 6.3. I want a sprite node to follow along a defined path. I also want the position of the node following the defined path to be relative to the, in this case y coordinate change, of the other node.[image]

The pink one is the one I move with my finger. Its "path" is from the origin to the horizontal pink line. If I drag it up 20% of its path I want the other two to move 20% in the same time. If I drag it back it will make the others go backwards on their path as well. The black dots represent this.
I'm sorry for not posting any code. I read about following a path in SpriteKit but nothing of what i found would have helped here. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Has anyone got an idea?

Comment: As of now I have been able to solve the problem. If anyone stumbles over this question wondering the same as I did, just leave a comment and I'll reply.